# React Context defaultValue returns undefined when no provider is wrapped around the component tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have been reading react docs to refresh my concepts. While reading, I came across this statement in context section:

> The value argument passed to the function will be equal to the value
> prop of the closest Provider for this context above in the tree. If
> there is no Provider for this context above, the value argument will
> be equal to the defaultValue that was passed to createContext().

So naturally, I created some snippets to actually test the scenario.

My entry point (App.js):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import WearLacoste from "./wearLacoste";
import WearPrada from "./wearPrada";
import OutFitProvider from "./outfitContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>What to wear?</h1>
      <OutFitProvider>
        <WearPrada />
      </OutFitProvider>
      <WearLacoste />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that I have two components. These components return a string rendered on the browser, telling which dress to wear. One of the component name `<WearPrada />` is wrapped by the provider, the other (`<WearLacoste/>`) is not, to test the `defaultValue` scenario.

Following is my context file (outfitContext.js):

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

const MyOutfitContext = React.createContext("Lacoste");

//a custom hook to consume context
export const useOutfit = () => {
  return useContext(MyOutfitContext);
};

const OutfitContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [outfit, setOutfit] = useState("Prada");

  return (
    <MyOutfitContext.Provider value={{ outfit }}>
      {children}
    </MyOutfitContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default OutfitContextProvider;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And finally both of my components, which do the exact same thing.

wearPrada.js :

```js
import { useOutfit } from "./outfitContext";

const WearPrada = () => {
  const { outfit } = useOutfit();
  console.log("Outfit expects Prada", outfit);
  return <h1>Wearing {outfit} RN </h1>;
};

export default WearPrada;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

wearLacoste.js :

```js
import { useOutfit } from "./outfitContext";

const WearLacoste = () => {
  const { outfit } = useOutfit();
  console.log("Outfit expects Lacoste", outfit);
  return <h1>Wearing {outfit} RN </h1>;
};

export default WearLacoste;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**My problem is:**

The component wrapped in the provider is behaving as expected. It gets the *state* value initialised in *context*. But as claimed in the document, the component not wrapped in the provider still gets an `undefined` value instead of the `defaultValue` which is `Lacoste` (see outfitContext.js). Am I doing anything wrong here? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The component is called `OutfitContextProvider` while in App.js you use `OutFitProvider`. Is that just a mistake when posting the question?

Comment: @Anton would that matter in a default export? And yes that was a posting error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: no your right, it wouldn't. i'm unused to default exports, that's why i noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have mixed the object `{ outfit: string }` with a simple string. The context value is expected to be an object everywhere but when setting the default value you use a string.

I believe what you want is `const MyOutfitContext = React.createContext({ outfit: "Lacoste" });`